# ASP.NET Core 1.1 Development on RedHat Enterprise Linux 7.3

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, redhat

I'm have an [an ASP.NET Core application](https://github.com/Phaka/hello.git) that was created using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10. It works as expected running the following commands

```
cd src  
dotnet restore  
dotnet build 
cd Hello.Portal
dotnet run
```

See build.cmd in the repository for more details.

My next objective is to create a build.sh for RHEL 7, which would end up with an RPM (but that is outside the scope of this question). To prepare for that I did the following:

1. Create an RHEL 7.3 virtual machine in VMware Workstation
2. Followed the [instructions](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/net_core/1.1/html/getting_started_guide/gs_install_dotnet) to install dotnet core 1.1 in the VM.

I then ran the following commands on Windows 10 to create a self-contained deployment.

```
dotnet restore --runtime rhel.7-x64  
dotnet publish --framework netcoreapp1.1 --runtime rhel.7-x64
```

I then SFTP the output over to the VM and the application works as expected.

I then cloned the GIT repository to the RHEL VM and then ran the following commands, assuming that it would work the same way it did for Windows.

```
cd src  
dotnet restore  
dotnet build
```

However it failed with the following errors:

```
[werners@localhost src]$ dotnet restore  
warn : The folder '/home/werners/development/hello/src' does not contain a project to restore.  
[werners@localhost src]$ dotnet build  
Couldn't find 'project.json' in current directory  
[werners@localhost src]$
```

This looks rather suspicious.  So I logged out and logged back in and the ran the following commands:

```
[werners@localhost ~]$ scl enable rh-dotnetcore11 bash  
[werners@localhost ~]$ dotnet --version  
1.0.0-preview2-1-003176
```

On Windows, the version returns the following:

```
S:\hello\src>dotnet --version  
1.0.3
```

So it looks like rh-dotnetcore11 doesn't have the latest released version of .NET core command line.

To validate, I ran the following as root.

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install rh-dotnetcore11  
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager  
Package rh-dotnetcore11-1.0-1.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version  
Nothing to do
```

What instructions does one follow to use Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.3 to build, test, run and publish ASP.NET Core application that was created with Visual Studio 2017?  .

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux ;) The download link has the latest ones for sure and on the bottom there's also a download script

Comment: If you created your project with Visual Studio 2017, it will create your project using csproj instead of project.json. "dotnet --version" is for the .NET Command Line Interface (CLI) and not your runtime or sdk version.

Comment: The CLI version *is* the SDK version.

Comment: @Tseng It is unfortunate that the `dotnet-install.sh` doesn't install under RHEL 7.3 without some changes. Once that is fixed, version 1.0.1 is installed which supports csproj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So it looks like rh-dotnetcore11 doesn't have the latest released version of .NET core command line.

It doesn't. The original release of .NET Core 1.0 had an RC version of CLI (or the SDK, if you will). This was packaged as rh-dotnetcore10 (and later an updated version was rh-dotnetcore11).

Due to compatibility requirements, RHEL packages can not break the command line interface and API.

The 1.0 SDK changed how the command line behaves and the project format; as such it was not suitable for inclusion into RHEL since it would break people's existing workflow and require migration from project.json to csproj.

As such, the RHEL packages contain the latest APIs (corefx and/or coreclr) but the older RC-era SDK.

> What instructions does one follow to use Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.3 to build, test, run and publish ASP.NET Core application that was created with Visual Studio 2017?

Unfortunately, there's no good path forward right now. Some options include:

- Using an upstream install of dotnet, something which won't be supported by Red Hat since it's not the official Red Hat package: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/cli/master/scripts/obtain/dotnet-install.sh
- Use the RC version of the SDK on Windows, Visual Studio 2015 (2017 doesn't support project.json) and rh-dotnetcore11 on RHEL.
- Wait a bit for 2.0 (hopefully releases soon) which should have the new SDK since Red Hat does not aim for compatibility between 1.0 and 2.0.

Comment: Oddly enough there is also a package of rh-dotnetcore10 for .NET Core 1.0.  So it seems that despite following semantic versioning, the .NET Core team broke a cardinal rule, that the major version should change when you break compatibility with a previous version.

Comment: @bloudraak SDK incompatibility does not mean runtime compatibility. Red Hat made a wrong decision when they created such packages, and I think they are the ones to be blamed.

Comment: @LexLi looking back at the outputs, Red Hat packaged preview code in a release channel. Their documentation contributes to the illusion that .NET Core 1.1 SDK is compatible to that on other platforms.

Comment: @LexLi Semantic versioning doesn't only apply to binaries produced by the SDK. When you break the "interface" of the tools, versioning has to reflect that. So I'd would have expected that at a minimum, the CLI toolset would have bumped the minor version since it had a breaking change in the underlying project format. I thus maintain that both parties are at fault.

Comment: @bloudraak "Red Hat packaged preview code in a release channel". We released what was officially released as .NET Core 1.0 (including the SDK which was a "preview") in a supported channel. We promise compatibility so we can't break the command line now that a "non-preview" SDK was released. "Their documentation contributes to the illusion ..." Can you point me to this doc?

Comment: @bloudraak Red Hat should explicitly package the runtime and SDK separately. For the SDK part, I don't think "semantic versioning" should always be applied, as if between preview builds Microsoft would like to make a breaking change (JSON to XML as they did), nobody would like to see a .NET Core SDK 1.0 being skipped.

Comment: @omajid Here's the document I used: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/net_core/1.1/html/getting_started_guide/gs_install_dotnet

Comment: @LexLi Preview/beta builds isn't relevant in semantic versioning;  you almost expect things to break. What is relevant is the changes from dotnet core 1.0 to 1.1. The CLI tool went from 1.0.0 to 1.0.3. There is no indication that they are incompatible. In most systems, this is just a patch (that is, the software works exactly as it did before with a small fix here or there).

Comment: @omajid You may want to mention that as of 4/18/2017 the `install-dotnet.sh` will not work on RHEL 7.3 without any changes. It only recognizes 7.0 thru 7.2.

Comment: @bloudraak, Really? https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/master/scripts/obtain/dotnet-install.sh#L87-L88 handles RHEL 7, generally. Which script are you using? What's the error?

Comment: @bloudraak there are too many version numbers, so I don't expect you to fully understand. http://corefx.strikingly.com/ As the history tells, .NET Core SDK itself only becomes 1.0 stable on March 7, 2017. "The CLI tool went from 1.0.0 to 1.0.3" is simply a wrong statement. The CLI is part of SDK, so its 1.0.0 release was never part of Red Hat's packages.

Comment: @omajid Go to https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux and download https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh, which still explicitly checks for `"rhel.7.0" | "rhel.7.1" | "rhel.7.2"`

Comment: @omajid Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I think I'm good to go and build software on RHEL. Since you work at RH it would be beneficial if they produced packages with the released version of .NET Core SDK 1.0.0.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks. It is unfortunate that .NET Core 1.0 was released in June 2016 with a preview SDK. This is at the root of the problem. Given how important the SDK is in the productivity of developing .NET core 1.0 applications, I'm not sure what folks were thinking vendors like RH would do. I'm still of the opinion that version numbers should have changed in the SDK to show that it was incompatible. And a version of the SDK should have been released when .NET core 1.0 was released.